# Why won't this PL/SQL function compile?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I'm learning about Oracle Apex, Oracle SQL and PL/SQL and I'm currently learning about functions.  I have written a function in which a table is created, data is stored and the table is returned to the calling query.  The problem is the code won't compile.  I can't see where the problem may be and I've compared the code to various online resources including this site.  Everything looks fine to me, so the answer is not obvious to me.

This is the code I wrote:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_table AS OBJECT
(
  futureValues NUMBER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_futureValues AS TABLE OF t_table;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "CALCULATE_VALUE"( lastRowMinus0 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1,
                                                   lastRowMinus1 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 2,
                                                   lastRowMinus2 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 3,
                                                   lastRowMinus3 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 4,
                                                   lastRowMinus4 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 5,
                                                   lastRowMinus5 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 6,
                                                   lastRowMinus6 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 7 )
RETURN t_futureValues AS 
                        tableObject         t_futureValues;
                        predictedValue      NUMBER := 0;
                        lastRowMinus0Value  NUMBER := 0;
                        lastRowMinus1Value  NUMBER := 0;
                        lastRowMinus2Value  NUMBER := 0;
                        lastRowMinus3Value  NUMBER := 0;
                        lastRowMinus4Value  NUMBER := 0;
                        lastRowMinus5Value  NUMBER := 0;
                        lastRowMinus6Value  NUMBER := 0;
                        avgDiff             NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN

        tableObject := t_futureValues();

        lastRowMinus0Value := 3;
        lastRowMinus1Value := 6;
        lastRowMinus2Value := 9;
        lastRowMinus3Value := 12;
        lastRowMinus4Value := 14;
        lastRowMinus5Value := 20;
        lastRowMinus6Value := 60;

        avgDiff := (lastRowMinus5Value - lastRowMinus6Value) + avgDiff;
        avgDiff := (lastRowMinus4Value - lastRowMinus5Value) + avgDiff;
        avgDiff := (lastRowMinus3Value - lastRowMinus4Value) + avgDiff;
        avgDiff := (lastRowMinus2Value - lastRowMinus3Value) + avgDiff;
        avgDiff := (lastRowMinus1Value - lastRowMinus2Value) + avgDiff;
        avgDiff := (lastRowMinus0Value - lastRowMinus1Value) + avgDiff;
        avgDiff := avgDiff / 6;                                            

        predictedValue := avgDiff + lastRowMinus0Value;                    

        begin
            for i in 2..13 loop
                predictedValue := predictedValue + avgDiff;

                IF predictedValue < 0 THEN
                   predictedValue := 0;
                END IF;

                insert into tableObject(futureValues)
                values(predictedValue);

            end loop;
        end;

        RETURN (tableObject);

END;
```

The error message I get is:

*ORA-06545: PL/SQL: compilation error - compilation aborted ORA-06550: line 6, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" ORA-06550: line 0, column 0: PLS-00565: T_TABLE must be completed as a potential REF target (object type)*

I have no doubt that the problem is something simple, so if anyone knows, then I'd be grateful.

Comment: So,  is line 6 the statement `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_futureValues AS TABLE OF t_table;` ?  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/errmg/PLS-00049.html#GUID-C2E95CDD-E8D5-4A63-90C2-41B66DD76B27 abd search for 00565 for the full reason, but understanding the full reason is beyond my skills in that area.

Comment: try putting a `/` before `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_futureValues AS TABLE OF t_table`.

Comment: Could it be that you are missing a slash character `/` between the first `CREATE TYPE` and the second `CREATE TYPE` statements? (At least that's what you posted.)

Comment: I had tried placing the slash there previously, but that too gave me the same error message.

Comment: @MarkStewart Yes, line 6 is the one you've identified.  I too researched the error code, but applying the suggested solution is also beyond me.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, I finally got it to compile.  I placed each 'CREATE AND REPLACE' statement in their own script and ran them separately. I then modified my function as suggested by @BrianLeach to replace the INSERT INTO statement with the following: tableobject.extend(); tableobject(tableobject.count).futureValues := predictedValue;    (It's all part of the learning experience).

Comment: Your first `create or replace type` was missing the terminating `/` required by many tools, as a couple of earlier comments mentioned. Probably you received a different error when you fixed that, so you took it out again.

Answer (score 2):

I don't work with types very often, but your insert is trying to insert into an array. A table must be the target of an insert.

Use the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE brianl.t_table AS OBJECT
(
  futureValues NUMBER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE brianl.t_futureValues AS TABLE OF t_table;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION brianl."CALCULATE_VALUE"( lastRowMinus0 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1,
                                                   lastRowMinus1 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 2,
                                                   lastRowMinus2 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 3,
                                                   lastRowMinus3 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 4,
                                                   lastRowMinus4 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 5,
                                                   lastRowMinus5 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 6,
                                                   lastRowMinus6 IN NUMBER DEFAULT 7 )
RETURN t_futureValues AS 
                        tableObject         t_futureValues;
                        predictedValue      NUMBER := 0;
                        lastRowMinus0Value  NUMBER := 0;
                        lastRowMinus1Value  NUMBER := 0;
                        lastRowMinus2Value  NUMBER := 0;
                        lastRowMinus3Value  NUMBER := 0;
                        lastRowMinus4Value  NUMBER := 0;
                        lastRowMinus5Value  NUMBER := 0;
                        lastRowMinus6Value  NUMBER := 0;
                        avgDiff             NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN

        tableObject := t_futureValues();

        lastRowMinus0Value := 3;
        lastRowMinus1Value := 6;
        lastRowMinus2Value := 9;
        lastRowMinus3Value := 12;
        lastRowMinus4Value := 14;
        lastRowMinus5Value := 20;
        lastRowMinus6Value := 60;

        avgDiff := (lastRowMinus5Value - lastRowMinus6Value) + avgDiff;
        avgDiff := (lastRowMinus4Value - lastRowMinus5Value) + avgDiff;
        avgDiff := (lastRowMinus3Value - lastRowMinus4Value) + avgDiff;
        avgDiff := (lastRowMinus2Value - lastRowMinus3Value) + avgDiff;
        avgDiff := (lastRowMinus1Value - lastRowMinus2Value) + avgDiff;
        avgDiff := (lastRowMinus0Value - lastRowMinus1Value) + avgDiff;
        avgDiff := avgDiff / 6;                                            

        predictedValue := avgDiff + lastRowMinus0Value;                    

        begin
            for i in 2..13 loop
                predictedValue := predictedValue + avgDiff;

                IF predictedValue < 0 THEN
                   predictedValue := 0;
                END IF;


                tableobject.extend();
                tableobject(tableobject.count).futureValues := predictedValue;
--                insert into tableObject(futureValues)
--                values(predictedValue);

            end loop;
        end;

        RETURN (tableObject);

END;
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your response.  I altered my function to the way you suggested (without the 'brianl', of course) but unfortunately I get the same error message.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  Your suggestion, together with separating out the scripts, worked.